# yii2 - Date range Picker not search between selected date

Tags: php, search, yii2, daterangepicker

My date range picker query is not search between the selected date.

Here the query in search model :

```
->andFilterWhere(['between', 'CREATED_DATE', $this->date_from, $this->date_to]
```

With that query, it's only find the date_from. It's not find the selected date range.

Here my view code :

```
  <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
      'action' => ['report'],
      'method' => 'get',
  ]);
  $model = new InstallmentSearch();?>
  <?= $form->field($model, 'date_from')->widget(DateRangePicker::className(), [
      'attributeTo' => 'date_to',
      'form' => $form, // best for correct client validation
      'language' => 'en',
      'size' => 'sm',
      'clientOptions' => [
          'autoclose' => true,
          'format' => 'yyyy-mm-dd'
      ]
  ]);?>
  <?= Html::submitButton('<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-play"></i>', ['class' => 'btn btn-success pull-right']) ?><br>
  <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
</div><br><br><br><br><br>
```

And I already public the variable in my search model

```
public $date_from;
public $date_to;
```

Solved with this query:

```
->andFilterWhere(['between', 'DATE_FORMAT(CREATED_DATE, "%Y-%m-%d")', $this->date_from, $this->date_to]
```

Comment: Could add the values of date_from and date_to? And the column type of CREATED_DATE? It could simply be a typo or something similar.

Comment: Check out my view code below.

Comment: You should remove that answer and edit your question. There's a button just below the blue tags called "Edit"

Comment: Deleted already. Sorry about that.

Comment: Check date formats, may be  differ from database format

Comment: Actually it's different, in my database I use yyyy-mm-dd H:i:s instead of yyyy-mm-dd. But, with that query I actually already get the data but not at date range. It is only search from the date_from.

Comment: Try using `->andFilterWhere(['between', 'DATE_FORMAT(CREATED_DATE, "%Y-%m-%d")', $this->date_from, $this->date_to]` for mysql

Comment: Well it's running perfectly with that query. Thanks a lot

Comment: Update your question with raw query executed in search.

Comment: I mean sql query executed. not activerecord condition :)

Comment: Well, all set dude. It's run perfectly. Thanks :)

Comment: Great :) Glad to help.